# Upload sphinx-generated documentation to pypi over https

Tags: python-sphinx, pypi, twine

Now that PyPI has been moved to new version and `upload_docs` command fails with `Upload failed (410): Gone (This API has been deprecated and removed from legacy PyPI`, what do I use to upload `.rst` files?

Twine developers seem to have expressed resolve not to support this functionality in https://github.com/pypa/twine/issues/12

Apart from migrating to one PDF to be uploaded via web interface, what options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading docs to Warehouse, the new PyPI, is not an option. Options include:

- Run your own PyPI mirror with [devpi](https://devpi.net/docs/devpi/devpi/latest/%2Bd/index.html) or similar.
- Use [Read the Docs](https://readthedocs.org/) or similar.